# How to convert string formatted array into normal array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, integer

I have array a="[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]".How can I convert this array to normal list format in Python like a=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] where I can directly access elements using an index?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ast` as the other answer recommends. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)
Be caution with useing `eval`. You can open doors for vunerabilities.

```
eval("[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]")
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

**Update:** `ast` gives you errors if the input isn't a valid Python.

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval("[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]")
```

Comment: [`eval is eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/4985099) avoid it !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ast, which is safer than eval.

```
import ast
a="[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]"
x = ast.literal_eval(a)
```